# PowerBI Guage - Percentage Split as target

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have some data about Online vs PhoneCalls (Channel).  With a Count of the Id column for the number based on that split.

The target is to aim for a (Online) 60/40 (Phone) split of channel, thus targeting a shift to more web then phone calls.

The data-source currently looks like this:

```
  Id |  DateCreated          | Channel 
-------------------------------------------

51556   2016-05-23 09:09:51.690 Phone
51557   2016-05-23 09:09:55.807 Web     
51558   2016-05-23 09:13:45.503 Phone   
51561   2016-05-23 09:22:24.037 Web     
51663   2016-05-23 14:00:00.787 Web     
51567   2016-05-23 09:35:52.323 Phone   
51574   2016-05-23 09:49:10.223 Web     
51576   2016-05-23 09:53:04.597 Web     
51588   2016-05-23 10:22:00.157 Phone   
51589   2016-05-23 10:23:35.987 Web     
51590   2016-05-23 10:31:24.880 Phone
```

I'm struggling to determine how to get this to fit into the built in PowerBI Gauge.

I've been trying to use the Count(Id) as the value, but I suspect I need to shape the data differently.  Possibly in SQL?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Whats the actual problem? surely when you put that data against a gauge you see the expected split? Do you think the gauge is showing incorrect numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would add following measures:

```
PhoneCount = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Channel]="Phone")) 
WebCount = COUNTROWS(FILTER(Table1,Table1[Channel]="Web")) 
WebToPhone = [WebCount]/([PhoneCount]+[WebCount])
TargetRatio% = 0.6
TargetRatio = TargetRatio% * COUNTROWS(table1)
```

Then I would change `Format` of `WebToPhone` and `TargetRatio%` to `Percentage` (Modelling tab).

Then you can either:

- Have a gauge with `WebCount` as `Value`, `Count of Id` as `Maximum Value` and `TargetRatio` as `Target Value`

Or

- Have a gauge with `WebToPhone` as a Value and `TargetRatio%` as `Target Value`

Change `table1` in measures (and rename gauge titles) appropriately.

[image]